# Why this cloud function is not working for email verification?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created a cloud function that sends a email verification link via email when a user is created through firebase authentication but its not working could anyone help me out

```js
exports.verifyemail = functions
  .region("asia-south1")
  .auth.user()
  .onCreate((user) => {
    return sendEmailVerification(user);
  });
```

Error log
[image: Error log]

Comment: I'm using firebase cloud functions and it serverless functions so it has a region

Comment: sorry, I really should read the questions more thoroughly :p anyway ... isn't it `module.exports`? or is that some other thing I'm getting wrong :p

Comment: "its not working" is incredibly hard to help with. What exactly isn't working when you run this code? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The [`sendEmailVerification` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#sendemailverification) only exists in the client-side SDKs of Firebase. It does (by design) not exist in the Admin SDKs, as they don't have the concept of a current user. Allowing you to send verification messages to any user in the project would make the process even more prone to being abuse to send spam than it already is.

You'll have to either call the `sendEmailVerification` from the client where the user logged in, or you'll have to implement your own email sending and verification mechanism on the server.

Comment: Then what could I do any suggestion

Comment: You'll have to either call the `sendEmailVerification` from the client where the user logged in, or you'll have to implement your own email sending and verification mechanism on the server.